# PHP script on mySQL table : FROM_UNIXTIME and INTO OUTFILE issues

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my first php script for a mysql table.

mySQL table looks as below :

[image]

From that table i would like to generate a dynamic HTML table with the following requirements :

- HTML table sorted ASC by NEXT_EVENT
- HTML table gets a new column showing NEXT_EVENT value as human readable datetime.

Once the table is sorted i need to output ID and NEXT_EVENT values from the very first row to a TXT file, the 2 values will be comma separared.

I tryed to write a PHP script, but it get errors.

Sorting ASC looks working properly, but conversion with FROM UNIXTIME does not and file output won't work either.

`mysql table's name is : 'webpilot'`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");

$table = '<table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>NEXT_EVENT</th>
            </tr>';

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(".$row['NEXT_EVENT'].") as $datetime");               

        $table .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['NAME'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['NEXT_EVENT'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$datetime.'</td>
                   </tr>';
    }
} else {
    $table .= '<tr><td colspan="3">No date found</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;

$fileoutput = mysql_query($conn, "SELECT ID,NAME,NEXT_EVENT FROM webpilot INTO OUTFILE '/next_event.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

The live result can be seen here : http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/dyntable.php

but i had to comment out the following line, as it reports an error avoiding the rest of script to be run and php webpage to be displayed.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(.$row['NEXT_EVENT']) as $datetime");
```

Line 203 is related to that line :

```
$fileoutput = mysql_query($conn,"SELECT ID,NAME,NEXT_EVENT FROM webpilot INTO OUTFILE '/next_event.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

Would you please show me how to get expected result.

Comment: change `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME` to `SELECT FROM UNIXTIME`
`SELECT FROM UNIXTIME(".$row['NEXT_EVENT'].") as $datetime`

Comment: Isn't the value of `$row['NEXT_EVENT']` already a unix timestamp to start with? Then forget about your second query and just echo it with: `<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['NEXT_EVENT']); ?>`. PHP is perfectly capable to convert a unix timestamp to a nice date using the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)-command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can you check mysql function is wrong **mysql_query** is there u know that
>   one you need to change **mysqli_query**

```
$fileoutput = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ID,NAME,NEXT_EVENT FROM webpilot INTO `OUTFILE '/next_event.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");`
```

and

> $datetime you need to assign values. Example like **$datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s")**

Answer (score 0):

HTML table sorted ASC by NEXT_EVENT (You are correct)

```
SELECT * FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC
```

HTML table gets a new column showing NEXT_EVENT value as human readable datetime. (You can try to more easy way, do inside php)

```
$getDateTime = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT NEXT_EVENT FROM webpilot where NEXT_EVENT=".$row['NEXT_EVENT'].");

$rowDateTime = mysqli_fetch_array($getDateTime );

$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $rowDateTime('NEXT_EVENT'));
```

MYSQL ways:

```
SELECT ID, FAVORITE, NAME, ORDERTYPE, STATE, LAST_EVENT RECCURENCY, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as datetime FROM webpilot ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

so your this code`mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(".$row['NEXT_EVENT'].") as $datetime");` can be remove.

Comment: Why in the world would you do that query? You're just fetching _the same value_ as you have in the `WHERE`. It's like: _"I want to know what the value is where the value is 5."_ You already _have_ that value. The query is totally useless! Forget about that query and just use `$row['NEXT_EVENT']` directly instead.

Comment: "SELECT ID, FAVORITE, NAME, ORDERTYPE, STATE, LAST_EVENT RECCURENCY, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as datetime FROM webpilot ORDER BY timestamp ASC"

Just want you try the easiest way if you can't thinking of it

Comment: @Ricky Can you show me how to integrate your suggested code modification in my PHP script ?   i tried to modify the php script but i think i still did something wrong because i still get errors.  This is my new php script source code : http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/phpscript_v1.txt

Comment: `$row['NEXT_EVENT']  `
change to `$row['datetime'];`
the `$datetime` can be removed

Comment: if you want show the NEXT_EVENT value, your mysql can be like this: `$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ID, NAME, **NEXT_EVENT**,  FROM_UNIXTIME(NEXT_EVENT) as datetime FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");` your php is like this $row['NEXT_EVENT'];